# Can't build rtl8821ce driver for debian 10

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, drivers

I tried installing the endlessm and tomaspinho driver, i got the same error after finishing  the make:

```
/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c: In function ‘rtw_android_priv_cmd’:
/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:665:49: error: macro "access_ok" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
  if (!access_ok(priv_cmd.buf, priv_cmd.total_len)) {

/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:665:7: error: ‘access_ok’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (!access_ok(priv_cmd.buf, priv_cmd.total_len)) {
       ^~~~~~~~~

/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c:665:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:309：/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o] error 1

make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-common/Makefile:1539：_module_/home/wjm/Templates/rtl8821ce-git20190810] error 2

make[2]: *** [Makefile:146：sub-make] error 2

make[1]: *** [Makefile:8：all] error  2

make[1]: leave “/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64”

make: *** [Makefile:2237：modules] error 2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That is using a 5.0 API, try this patch:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rkitover/5c747964cafcebf7222d543e8270fa9a/raw/46308574053fe57bdcbbf1ed2dc61d8e47e3b50f/rtl8821ce_4_19.patch

Comment: I submitted a PR to the tomasphine repo: https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/pull/61